# How do I use custom Button and Bootstrap Button In a React App for Different Pages?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button, bootstrap-4

I've been following a tutorial and I want to keep their styling for Buttons and Navbars but I also want to  implement some bootstrap for components such as buttons. However when I import the Buttons from bootstrap their styling is not there. Is there something I can do to fix this?

Also, If I import the bootstrap.min.css file on the signup page, the buttons regain their styling but the whole website is affected by the bootstrap css.

[HomepageButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1V5a.jpg)     [SignupPageButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjgI6.png) [BootstrapButton](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YaKf.png)
[When Bootstrap.min.css Is Imported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If613.jpg)

Button Component From Tutorial

```
import React from 'react';
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const STYLES = ['btn--primary', 'btn--outline', 'btn--test'];

const SIZES = ['btn--medium', 'btn--large'];

export const Button = ({
  children,
  type,
  onClick,
  buttonStyle,
  buttonSize
}) => {
  const checkButtonStyle = STYLES.includes(buttonStyle)
    ? buttonStyle
    : STYLES[0];

  const checkButtonSize = SIZES.includes(buttonSize) ? buttonSize : SIZES[0];

  return (
    <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-mobile'>
      <button
        className={`btn ${checkButtonStyle} ${checkButtonSize}`}
        onClick={onClick}
        type={type}
      >
        {children} 
      </button>
    </Link>
  );
};
```

HomePage with Custom Button

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Button } from './Button';
import './HeroSection.css';

function HeroSection() {
  return (
    
    <div className='hero-container'>
      <video src='/videos/video.mp4' autoPlay loop muted />
      <h1>HELLO</h1>
      {/* <p>What are you waiting for!</p> */}
      <div className='hero-btns'>
        <Button
          className='btns'
          buttonStyle='btn--outline'
          buttonSize='btn--large'
        >
          GET STARTED
        </Button>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeroSection;
```

Sign Up Page with Bootstrap Button

```
import React from 'react';
/* import '../App.css';*/



/* import { Button } from '../components/Button';  */

import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';


export default function SignUp() {
  return(
      <> 
      <h1 className='sign-up'>Sign Up</h1> { /*This Keeps Its styling*/ }
      <Button className= "py-3" variant="success" href="/">Hello</Button> {/* This does not keep its styling */}
      
      </>
      
      
      );
}
```

Comment: check my answer and demo

Comment: Where can I find your demo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your Button component name because there is a conflict between your component and the Button component of react-bootstrap (they have the same name).

Also, be careful with class names in your css file. 'btn' is used by react-bootstrap ...

Demo: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nttslu?file=src%2FHeroSection.js)