# Why after i import React Bootstrap my previous button design not work?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

After i `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';`at `App.js` my previous design for button is not work like color and size. 
I had create a `button.js` and `button.css` for the button design.
and use `import { Button } from './Button';` to link it. 
I am using `{button && <Button buttonStyle='btn--outline'>register</Button>}` to use the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your component is called Button and the react-bootstrap component is also called Button, there is a conflict.

Change the name of your component (CustomButton for example)

Check this page and my demo : [How do I use custom Button and Bootstrap Button In a React App for Different Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66673678/how-do-i-use-custom-button-and-bootstrap-button-in-a-react-app-for-different-pag/66705949#66705949)